# CSS - nth-child with 12 layers of nested div classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've inherited a Joomla CMS and have been asked to make changes.  Currently on the site, there is an addon built on owl-carousel.  There are a series of slides, each with their own background image.  There are three text elements displayed over the background image - a title, a sub title, and a line of detailed text.  As constructed, the same style is being applied to all slides.  The problem is there is a need to change the background images, some will be light and some will be dark.  This requires being able to change the text formatting per element per slide, so that the text can be easily read with the background image

I'm not very sophisticated with CSS and I can't figure out how to write the CSS with so many layers.  I think it's probably not difficult, I just don't know where to start.  All of my searches have yielded simple examples but nothing like the complexity in my situation.

I've set up a jsfiddle to help with this.  In it I made things generic and stripped out everything but the elements I need to style.  http://jsfiddle.net/x40p6nb1/

```
<div id=“sppb-addon-1482142525696” class=“clearfix”>                                                
<div class=“sppb-addon sppb-slider-wrapper sppb-slider-fullwidth-wrapper owl-theme”>                                
    <div class=“sppb-slider-item-wrapper”>                                      
        <div id=“slide-fullwidth” class=“owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded”>                                    
            <div class=“owl-stage-outer”>                               
                <div class=“owl-stage”>                         
                    <div class=“owl-item”>                      
                        <div class=“sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item item”>                    
                            <div class=“sppb-slide-item-bg sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item-bg”>               
                                <div class=“container”>         
                                    <div class=“sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item-text”>        
                                        <h1 class=“sppb-fullwidth-title”>   
                                            <small class=“sppb-slidehsow-sub-title”>Sub Title 1</small><br>TITLE 1</h1> 
                                        <p class=“details”>Details 1</p>    
                                    </div>      
                                </div>          
                            </div>              
                        </div>                  
                    </div>                      
                    <div class=“owl-item”>                      
                        <div class=“sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item item”>                    
                            <div class=“sppb-slide-item-bg sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item-bg”>               
                                <div class=“container”>         
                                    <div class=“sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item-text”>        
                                        <h1 class=“sppb-fullwidth-title”>   
                                            <small class=“sppb-slidehsow-sub-title”>Sub Title 2</small><br>TITLE 2</h1> 
                                        <p class=“details”>Details 2</p>    
                                    </div>      
                                </div>          
                            </div>              
                        </div>                  
                    </div>                      
                    <div class=“owl-item”>                      
                        <div class=“sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item item”>                    
                            <div class=“sppb-slide-item-bg sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item-bg”>               
                                <div class=“container”>         
                                    <div class=“sppb-slideshow-fullwidth-item-text”>        
                                        <h1 class=“sppb-fullwidth-title”>   
                                            <small class=“sppb-slidehsow-sub-title”>Sub Title 3</small><br>TITLE 3</h1> 
                                        <p class=“details”>Details 3</p>    
                                    </div>      
                                </div>          
                            </div>              
                        </div>                  
                    </div>                      
                </div>                          
            </div>                              
        </div>                                  
    </div>                                      
</div>
```

Here's what I need to do.

I want Sub Title 1 (line 15; the first instance of class="sppb-slidehsow-sub-title") to be {color: #575757 !important;}

I want TITLE 1 (line 15; the first instance of class="sppb-fullwidth-title") to be {color: #d2373c !important;}

I want Details 1 (line 16; the first instance of class="details") to be {color: #707070 !important; font-weight: 600 !important;}

I want Sub Title 2 (line 28; the second instance of class="sppb-slidehsow-sub-title") to be {color: #ff0000 !important;}

I want TITLE 2 (line 28; the second instance of class="sppb-fullwidth-title") to be {color: #00ff00 !important;}

I want Details 2 (line 29; the second instance of class="details") to be {color: #0000ff !important; font-weight: 600 !important;}

I want Sub Title 3 (line 41; the third instance of class="sppb-slidehsow-sub-title") to be {color: #ffff00 !important;}

I want TITLE 3 (line 41; the third instance of class="sppb-fullwidth-title") to be {color: #ff00ff !important;}

I want Details 3 (line 42; the third instance of class="details") to be {color: #00ffff !important; font-weight: 600 !important;}

Can anyone help me out with this?  Point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, fix your HTML code - you need to use either `"` or `'` as attribute delimiters, not `“`curly quotes`”`.

Comment: And then, the nesting level is only of interest in one regard here - that you need to “count” the children on the right level. You want to apply different styles per slide, which owl calls items, so naturally `.owl-item:nth-child(...)` is what you want to base the distinction on. From there on you simply select “further down” using the descendant or child selector, and classes you need to target to apply the different properties to the relevant elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response CBroe.  I'm a total noob to html/css quite honestly.  My background is SQL and PL/SQL on Oracle.  I inherited this mess. 

The curly braces were from a custom.css file used elsewhere.  I just copied those in to the text of the message.  This is in a CMS so I have to make the style change in CSS.  As far as I can tell, the html works.  I ran it in the jsfiddle and it produces the content.  It's just the formatting that I need for the CSS.

.owl-item is what I thought to base it on.  I just don't know how to select further down.  Can't find a close example.

Comment: `.owl-item:nth-child(...) .sppb-slidehsow-sub-title { color: ...; }`, `.owl-item:nth-child(...) .sppb-fullwidth-title { color: ...; }` etc. pp.

Comment: I added this to the CSS in jsfiddle and nothing changed.  I'm not sure what I've missed.

.owl-item:nth-child(1) .sppb-slidehsow-sub-title {color: #575757 !important;}

.owl-item:nth-child(2) .sppb-fullwidth-title {color: #d2373c !important;}

.owl-item:nth-child(3) .details {color: #707070 !important; font-weight: 600 !important;}

Comment: I even changed the name of the first (of three) "owl-item" classes to "owl-item-active" so it is unique.  Then I used one line of CSS: .owl-item-active .sppb-fullwidth-title {color: #d2373c !important;}

That doesn't do anything either.  Shouldn't that have changed the text color?  I can' figure out why nothing is working...

Answer (score 0):

The CSS pseudo-class `:nth-of-type` is a pain, because most of us want it to be able to target element classes *as well as* element types... but it doesn't.

Instead, you can use the sibling combinator (`~`) to target classes in a manner similar to the way you might target element types using `:nth-of-type`.

**e.g.**

- `.details {color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}`
- `.details ~ .details {color: rgb(255, 127, 0);}`
- `.details ~ .details ~ .details {color: rgb(0, 127, 0);}`

**Working Example:**

```css
p {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.details {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.details ~ .details {
color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

.details ~ .details ~ .details {
color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
}

.details ~ .details ~ .details ~ .details {
color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>I am a paragraph.</p>

<p>I am another paragraph.</p>

<p class="details">I am the first instance of <code>class="details"</code>.</p>

<p>I am another paragraph.</p>

<p class="details">I am the second instance of <code>class="details"</code>.</p>

<p>I am another paragraph.</p>

<p>I am another paragraph.</p>

<p class="details">I am the third instance of <code>class="details"</code>.</p>

<p>I am another paragraph.</p>

<p class="details">I am the fourth instance of <code>class="details"</code>.</p>

<p class="details">I am the fifth instance of <code>class="details"</code>.</p>
```